# Move focus on keyup when maxlength is reached error

Tags: jquery

I have used Jquery to move the focus from 'input A' to 'input B' when maxlength is reached. Also, I have set it up so that when character value reaches 0 and backspace is pressed then the focus goes back to input A. 
This is so that the user can easily type in the two fields as if its one continous field.

The issue I am having is that when I have deleted all characters from input B and the focus switches back to 'input A' and I start typing, the first keypress is ignored (it does still switch the focus to 'input B').

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // Tab to next item when maxlength is reached
  $(".postcode div:nth-child(1) input").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
    }
  });

  // Tab to previous Item when backspace is pressed and length is 0
  $(".postcode div:nth-child(2) input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8) {
      if (this.value.length == 0) {
        $(this).parent().prev().find('input').focus();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postcode">
  <div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this bug in action by [clicking here](https://codepen.io/Rubenkretek/pen/PowNYKw)

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point, when you return to A from B, there are still 4 characters in the field, so pressing another one will move you to B - which is what your code does. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: That's right but I need the keypress to register and show up in 'input B' so that typing between the two boxes is seamless. At the moment the keypress is ignored and you have to press the key again for the character to be inputted in.

Comment: So in effect you need the delete in the empty B to remove the last character in A as well as switching focus, right?

Comment: No. Lets pretend that the two inputs are one input box. If I type in 5 characters, and then delete one, the next keypress should add a new 5th character. Right now when typing in the 5th character it focuses on the next input but ignores the actual character. You can replicate this by typing in 'AAAAC' then deleteing the 'C' and the trying to type a new character. The focus will shift to 'input B' but will not type in the new character you have entered. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense, however doing it in that manner will result in problems if the user types in the second box first (and they will because users love to break things :)

Comment: I tend to agree that when B is empty, don't move to box A.  If user presses backspace in empty B then move to box A and remove last character.  As it is, it feels odd to have cursor at end of A with 4 chars.  Perhaps your css would alleviate this and make it more seamless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameter on your event so that the context of the event will be stored in it. From there we could get what type of button or character did the user click. I used `e` and get the value via `e.key`.

I added another event handler which is `keypress`. The other answer placed the value assignment in `keyup` *which will populate the user click twice when the maxlength is reached* (one input on 1st field, another input on 2nd field). By using keypress, we were able to determine the length of the fields prior to the actual input on the field.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // Tab to next item when maxlength is reached
  $(".postcode div:nth-child(1) input").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
    }
  });

  // new event to handle keypress which happens before keyup
  $(".postcode div:nth-child(1) input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).parent().next().find('input').val(e.key);
    }
  });

  // Tab to previous Item when backspace is pressed and length is 0
  $(".postcode div:nth-child(2) input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8) {
      if (this.value.length == 0) {
        $(this).parent().prev().find('input').focus();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postcode">
  <div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the character limit for the first field, in addition to switching the focus, you need to save the pressed key value and set it as the second input's value.

You can get the value from the `keyup` handler event parameter and set it as the second field value. Currently you are just switching the focus, that's why you need to press the key twice.

Something like this:

`$(".postcode div:nth-child(1) input").keyup(function(event) {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {

      $(this).parent().next().find('input')
        .focus()
        .val(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
    }
  });`